# NoClassDefFoundError for apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Tags: android, exception, apache-stringutils

I want to use `commons-lang3` in my project, with Android Studio.

Here is my gradle configuration:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
```

Gradle build is done without error, I can use `StringUtils`. But in runtime, app crashes with this error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils;
```

I also tried with `.jar` in `lib` folder but I get the same error.

Comment: Do you use proguard?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

change your gradle file to this:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
```

then you can use this import in your classes:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```